# Why is numpy's exp slower than Matlab? How to make it faster?

Tags: python, matlab, performance, numpy

I have a pretty simple example which shows that NumPy's `np.exp` is about 10x slower than Matlab. How can I speed up Python? I'm running 32bit Python 2.7, NumPy version 1.11.3, and numpy is using the MKL blas & lapack libraries.

Also, the difference in time is so large that I don't think the timing mechanism is having a big effect.

Code example in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

setup='import numpy as np; import numexpr as ne; n=100*1000; a = np.random.uniform(size=n)'
time = timeit.timeit('b=np.exp(a)', setup=setup, number=1000)
print 'Time for 1000 (np.exp): ',time
time = timeit.timeit('b=ne.evaluate("exp(a)")', setup=setup, number=1000)
print 'Time for 1000 (numexpr): ',time
```

Results in:

```
Time for 1000 (np.exp):  2.25906916167
Time for 1000 (numexpr):  0.591470532849
```

In Matlab:

```
a = rand([100*1000,1]);
times = [];
for i=1:1000,
    tic
    b = exp(a);
    t=toc;
    times(i) = t;
end

fprintf('Time for 1000: %f\n',sum(times));
```

Resulting in:

```
Time for 1000: 0.268527
```

Comment: timeit docs say no multi-line string literals. I'm guessing the way you're passing in setup part if it is being evaluated as a part of your timeit run. You can do a direct apples-to-apples comparison by mimicking the tic/tock setup in matlab within python.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: The docs say `stmt` and `setup` can't *contain* multi-line string literals, not that they can't span multiple lines themselves. I believe this is because the [`reindent` helper](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/timeit.py#L90) `timeit` uses to adjust the indentation of multi-line input will mangle multi-line string literals in the input.

Comment: Also, as far as the question of how to make it faster, this actually has nothing to do with numpy and everything to do with the lapack you've got under the hood. If you want to improve it, that's where you've got to look.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the setup string to a single string separating with semicolons, same timing results.

Comment: @user2357112 My mistake. I've run into subtle issues with this in the past and failed to mentally parse the input string.

Comment: As it turns out, timing code for MATLAB isn't really *correct*. Check out the posted solution's end section for more info. A more trusted way would be with `timeit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To improve performance especially on large datasets, we can leverage [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) for such transcendental functions -

```
import numexpr as ne

b = ne.evaluate('exp(a)')
```

### Benchmarking

For a proper benchmarking, I would  use [`timeit on MATLAB`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) and [`NumPy's %timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) -

**Set #1**

MATLAB :

```
>> a = rand([100*1000,1]);
>> func = @() exp(a);
>> timeit(func)
ans =
    0.0013 % That's 1.3 m-sec
```

NumPy on identical sized dataset :

```
In [417]: n=100*1000
     ...: a = np.random.uniform(size=n)
     ...: 

In [418]: %timeit np.exp(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 ms per loop

In [419]: %timeit ne.evaluate('exp(a)')
1000 loops, best of 3: 397 µs per loop
```

Thus,

```
MATLAB  : 1.3 m-sec
NumPy   : 1.5 m-sec
Numexpr : 0.4 m-sec
```

**Set #2**

MATLAB :

```
>> a = rand([1000*10000,1]);
>> func = @() exp(a);
>> timeit(func)
ans =
    0.0977  % That's 97 m-sec
```

NumPy :

```
In [412]: n=1000*10000
     ...: a = np.random.uniform(size=n)
     ...: 

In [413]: %timeit np.exp(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop

In [414]: %timeit ne.evaluate('exp(a)')
10 loops, best of 3: 36.5 ms per loop
```

Thus,

```
MATLAB  :  97 m-sec
NumPy   : 154 m-sec
Numexpr :  36 m-sec
```

---

**Proper benchmarking with `tic-toc`**

Fault with the benchmarking in the question is that we are getting the toc elapsed timings within a loop that's not run for enough time to give us any accurate timings. The generally accepted idea is that `toc` elapsed timings must be at least close to `1` sec mark.

So, with those corrections, a more accurate timing test with `tic-toc` would be -

```
tic
for i=1:1000,
    b = exp(a);
end
t=toc;
timing = t./1000
```

This yields -

```
timing =
    0.0010
```

This is close to our `1.3 m-sec` with `timeit`.

Comment: The bigger question here is why your runs are a thousand times faster than OPs

Comment: My time results are for the total time of all exp(a) runs, not the average time for 1.

@Divakar -- I added the numexpr, that is good and helps a bunch, but still we are over 2x slower than Matlab.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Actually `%timeit` gets us the average of 1000 runs. OP is accumulating it and that's not averaged. Still, not sure how that became  the bigger question. We should be focusing on the speedups.

Comment: @Divakar ha, that would do it. Down to a 3-4x delta, which is much more reasonably a hardware delta.

Comment: @IsaacAsher Use your trusted `setup='import numpy as np; import num..` code and then use the tic-toc code that I have posted at the end of my post. What results do you get for the three versions : MATLAB, NumPy, Numexpr? Could you add that into the question or let me know in comments?

Comment: @IsaacAsher I tested at my end with your trusty `setup='import numpy as np; import num..` code and I am getting : `1.57 m-sec` for NumPy, `0.4 m-sec` for Numexpr` and those are close to the ones posted in this post using `%timeit`. With MATLAB using your trusted `tic-toc` after the corrections suggested at the end of my post are `1 m-sec`. `Numexpr` is easily beating MATLAB one. Does this conclude everything?

Comment: @IsaacAsher Forget about timings at my end. Your hardward config is different than mine. Its pointless to compare timings between yours and mine. Do all the timings at your end and then get the speedups and then see which one is fastest. Timings at my end have already been presented and numexpr has been proved to be the fastest.

Comment: @Divakar Again, the timings on my end haven't changed (ok, your new Matlab implementation went from 0.269s to 0.224s).  Matlab is still over 2x faster than numexpr on my machine.  Perhaps it is hardware, perhaps it is some other difference in the libraries being used... I suppose I'm willing to live with my current setup, but I'm still curious if there is a reason why my numexpr is slow that could be mitigated.

Comment: @IsaacAsher What's the runtime with `numexpr` at your end? Think I missed that.

Comment: @Divakar As noted in my edits of the original post, `numexpr` on my machine takes ~0.6s total or 0.6ms per call.  This is the same whether I use timeit.timeit or %timeit.