# How to accelerate convolving function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numba

I have written a convolving function like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import numba as nb

# Generate sample input data
num_chans = 111
num_bins = 47998 
num_rad = 8
num_col = 1000

rng = np.random.default_rng()

wvl_sensor = rng.uniform(low=1000, high=11000, size=(num_chans, num_col))
fwhm_sensor = rng.uniform(low=0.01, high=2.0, size=num_chans)

wvl_lut = rng.uniform(low=1000, high=11000, size=num_bins) 
rad_lut = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_rad, num_bins))

# Original convolution implementation
def original_convolve(wvl_sensor, fwhm_sensor, wvl_lut, rad_lut):

    sigma = fwhm_sensor / (2.0 * np.sqrt(2.0 * np.log(2.0)))  
    var = sigma ** 2
    denom = (2 * np.pi * var) ** 0.5
    
    numer = np.exp(-(wvl_lut[:, None] - wvl_sensor[None, :])**2 / (2*var)) 
    response = numer / denom
    
    response /= response.sum(axis=0)
    resampled = np.dot(rad_lut, response)
    
    return resampled
```

The numpy version runs about 45 s:

```
# numpy version
num_chans, num_col = wvl_sensor.shape
num_bins = wvl_lut.shape[0]
num_rad = rad_lut.shape[0]

original_res = np.empty((num_col, num_rad, num_chans), dtype=np.float64)

for x in range(wvl_sensor.shape[1]):
    original_res[x, :, :] = original_convolve(wvl_sensor[:, x], fwhm_sensor, wvl_lut, rad_lut)
```

I have tried to accelerate it using numba:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def numba_convolve(wvl_sensor, fwhm_sensor, wvl_lut, rad_lut):
    num_chans, num_col = wvl_sensor.shape
    num_bins = wvl_lut.shape[0]
    num_rad = rad_lut.shape[0]

    output = np.empty((num_col, num_rad, num_chans), dtype=np.float64)

    sigma = fwhm_sensor / (2.0 * np.sqrt(2.0 * np.log(2.0)))  
    var = sigma ** 2
    denom = (2 * np.pi * var) ** 0.5

    for x in nb.prange(num_col):
        numer = np.exp(-(wvl_lut[:, None] - wvl_sensor[None, :, x])**2 / (2*var))
        response = numer / denom

        response /= response.sum(axis=0)
        resampled = np.dot(rad_lut, response)
        output[x, :, :] = resampled

    return output
```

It still costs about 32s. Note that if I use `@nb.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)`, the output is all zero values.

Any idea to apply numba correctly? or improve the convolving function?

Comment: On my PC, almost 90% of the execution time was spent on numpy.exp. By changing this to [numexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190171/18125313), I was able to make the numpy version almost 3 times faster. Unfortunately, numba does not support numpexpr and I don't know of an alternative.

Comment: @ken Thanks. Using `numexpr` is a nice option. Could you write the example as answer? Because I got `'VariableNode' object is not subscriptable` when passing the numer expression directly.

Comment: @ken. Well, I find the correct method: `numer = ne.evaluate('exp(-(a-b)**2/(2*c))', {'a': wvl_lut[:, None], 'b': wvl_sensor[None, :], 'c': var})`. And it costs about 24s on my laptop ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the Numpy-like code in your Numba implementation with plain loops. Numba likes **plain loops**. This strategy helps to avoid creating many small temporary arrays or few large ones. Both causes scalability issues. Then you can **parallelize the computation** the outer loop (like you did).

There are other benefit of this strategy:

- `np.dot` use a *BLAS library* which is generally already parallel so using it in a parallel code can cause performance issues (though it can be tuned at the application level);
- high-level Numpy features in parallel Numba codes tend to be unfortunately more *bogus* (due to Numba itself), so using less advanced features avoid such issues (I have encountered this problem a few times).

Here is the resulting code:

```py
@nb.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def numba_convolve_faster(wvl_sensor, fwhm_sensor, wvl_lut, rad_lut):
    num_chans, num_col = wvl_sensor.shape
    num_bins = wvl_lut.shape[0]
    num_rad = rad_lut.shape[0]

    original_res = np.empty((num_col, num_rad, num_chans), dtype=np.float64)
    sigma = fwhm_sensor / (2.0 * np.sqrt(2.0 * np.log(2.0)))
    var = sigma ** 2
    denom = (2 * np.pi * var) ** 0.5
    inv_denom = 1.0 / denom
    factor = -1 / (2*var)

    for x in nb.prange(wvl_sensor.shape[1]):
        wvl_sensor_col = wvl_sensor[:, x].copy()
        response = np.empty(num_bins)
        for j in range(num_chans):
            response_sum = 0.0
            for i in range(num_bins):
                diff = wvl_lut[i] - wvl_sensor_col[j]
                response[i] = np.exp(diff * diff * factor[j]) * inv_denom[j]
                response_sum += response[i]
            inv_response_sum = 1.0 / response_sum
            for i in range(num_bins):
                response[i] *= inv_response_sum
            for k in range(num_rad):
                s = 0.0
                for i in range(num_bins):
                    s += rad_lut[k, i] * response[i]
                original_res[x, k, j] = s

    return original_res

res = numba_convolve_faster(wvl_sensor, fwhm_sensor, wvl_lut, rad_lut)
```

Output results are correct on my machine (with a ~1e-16 error). Note that the initial implementation produces NaN values like this one.

---

### Results

Here are performance results on my i5-9600KF CPU (with 6 cores):

```
OP Numpy code:    4min 37s
OP Numba code:    4min 24s
With Numexpr:     1min 13s
This Numba code:       46s     <-----
```

Thus, this new parallel Numba implementation is **5.74x faster** than the initial one. It is also faster than using Numexpr. This is close to optimal on my CPU with the default exponential function.

---

### Notes

The code can certainly be a bit faster using the exponential function of the Intel **SVML** library on x86-64 CPUs.

If you have a server-side **GPU**, then the code can be computed on it more efficiently (since this computation is GPU friendly). Mainstream PC GPU will likely not compute this faster than on CPU because Mainstream PC GPU are designed for simple-precision.

With **simple-precision**, the code can be significantly faster on both CPUs and GPUs especially if you do not need a very-high precision. This is because:

- Simple-precision exponential approximation can be computed in a very SIMD-friendly way while accurate double-precision exponential functions cannot really (it often does not worth it);
- Some basic simple-precision operations are faster (and consume less energy) than double-precision ones;
- SIMD registers can hold twice more simple-precision numbers than double-precision ones (often for the same cost per SIMD operation so the throughput is twice bigger with simple-precision numbers).